# Exhaustive combination of one row from each factor level in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have data like this

```
> df <- data.frame(group = c('A','B','B','C','C'),value=c(1,1,2,1,2))
> df
  group value
1     A     1
2     B     1
3     B     2
4     C     1
5     C     2
```

I would like to get all combination of one value from each group. In this case there are four:

```
 > df[c(1,2,4),]
      group value
    1     A     1
    2     B     1
    4     C     1
    > df[c(1,2,5),]
      group value
    1     A     1
    2     B     1
    5     C     2
    > df[c(1,3,4),]
      group value
    1     A     1
    3     B     2
    4     C     1
    > df[c(1,3,5),]
      group value
    1     A     1
    3     B     2
    5     C     2
```

Comment: do you mean giving different combination in such as `c(1,2,4)` in `df`?

Comment: yes, so essentially it is a combination of 1, one of (2,3), and one of (4,5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this will help:

```
> do.call(expand.grid,
+         lapply(levels(df$group), function (level) which(df$group == level)))
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    2    4
2    1    3    4
3    1    2    5
4    1    3    5
```

Comment: thank you, expand.grid is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: But, what is the third column `Var3`?

Comment: But, the OP never asked for it.

Comment: where did the OP asked it in question? and what does it mean?

Comment: OP's factor has **three levels**, and he/she wants combination of their occurrences.  Obviously those combinations are going to be **triples**.